# How to generate an unique number while saving the data in MVC using Entity Framework as per the max Identity key of the table?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have to short the below code.

I need to generate and save a unique reference number in the column as  `R00001`, `R00002`, `R00003`, etc. Here 1, 2 & 3 are based on the identity key values.

For this, I have written `db.SaveChanges()` twice. First I save the data and select that saved data and update it by generating that unique key. Is it possible to generate that key and passing while saving at once?

So, I do not need to select the data after saving and updating it by again calling `db.SaveChanges()` twice. Here is my MVC Controller (MVC action) code.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(RateTable model, HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
  RateTable objRC = null;
  if (model.RatecontractId >= 1)
  {
      objRC = db.RateTables.FirstOrDefault(rc => rc.RatecontractId == model.RatecontractId);
  }

  if (objRC == null && model.RatecontractId <= 0)
  {
      objRC = new RateTable();

      objRC.CountryCode = model.CountryCode;
      objRC.CompanyCode = model.CompanyCode;
      objRC.CustomerName = model.CustomerName;
      objRC.Remarks = model.Remarks;
      objRC.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
      objRC.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;

      //Saving data into the database table.
      db.RateTables.Add(objRC);
      db.SaveChanges();

      string uniqueRefNo = "R" + string.Format("{0:D5}", objRC.RatecontractId); 
      int rateContractId = objRC.RatecontractId;

      //For updating the unique reference number of the contract.
      RateTable result = (from rc in db.RateTables where rc.RatecontractId == rateContractId select rc).SingleOrDefault();
       if (result != null)
       {
          result.UniqueRefNo = uniqueRefNo;
          db.SaveChanges();
       }
   }
}
```

I save the data in `UniqueRefNo` column as shown below:

```
RatecontractId  CountryCd   CompanyCd   UniqueRefNo
---------------------------------------------------
1               C0U001      C0M001      R00001
2               C0U001      C0M001      R00002
3               C0U001      C0M001      R00003
4               C0U001      C0M001      R00004
5               C0U001      C0M001      R00005
```

I want to reduce this code because I am saving files also which needed to be saved in the format like `R00001.pdf`, `R00002.pdf`, `R00003.pdf`, etc.

Here is the file saving code with the renamed file name as per the unique reference number.

```
if (files != null)
{
  foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
  {
    if (file != null)
    {
      //To generate the file name of the rate contract.
      var fileName = "RC" + string.Format("{0:D5}", objRC.RatecontractId);
      var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
      fileName = fileName + extension;

      string path = string.Format("~/Documents/PDF/{0}", fileName);

       if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)))
          System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(path));
       file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));

       RateTable resultForfiles = (from rc in dbTender.RateTables where 
       rc.RatecontractId == objRC.RatecontractId select rc).SingleOrDefault();
       if (resultForfiles != null && (extension.ToLower() == "pdf" || extension.ToLower() == ".pdf"))
       {
          resultForfiles.PdfFilePath = fileName;
       }
       if (resultForfiles != null && extension.ToLower() != "pdf" && extension.ToLower() != ".pdf")
       {
          resultForfiles.WordExcelFilePath = fileName;
       }
       dbTender.SaveChanges(); //Third thime calling `SaveChanges()`
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: This seems a job for a trigger.

Comment: @Steve I know that and also done in C# code by writing code multiple time and want to know is any other way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: I would prefer using a computed column over a trigger for this. But this is something that needs to be done on the database, I don't know enough about entity framework to tell you if it's even possible to do directly from c#.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Noted. Here I have to save uploaded file with renamed name like R00001.pdf, R00002.pdf, etc. based on the identity key. The file name should be saved in DB and in folder actual file would also needed to renamed & saved. So, I need to do it by C# rather than the database side.

Comment: All Entity Framework solution requires a second call to the database whether you use your code, Execute SQL Statement or call a stored procedure. And for that, the trigger in the database level will be the best practice for that. See triger after insert: https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/41414/sql-server-coding-the-after-insert-trigger-in-sql-server/

Comment: I didn't see your last comment. Well, you can still update the UniqueRefNo at the database level using triggers. And for updating the file, the database part can be done by the same trigger and the C# part can be done using the object that comes from the database after the SaveChanges. So, you will save in both ways the second call to the database

Comment: @SamySammour Thats OK and currently I am doing it by C# by second call. Checking any better solution to short the repeated code. Thanks to you.

Comment: As I told you, the best solution will be to split the work between the database and the C#. Do all the database work using Triggers and the C# code parallel which will improve your performance for sure. Another thing you might do is a background job. In this case, the job will work in the background and you will absolutely improve the performance. Again, it is the question of the requirments.

Comment: I will write all the ideas in an answer for easy retrieval in the future.

Comment: What stops you from creating an identity column `Id` and keep logic of reference code in application? Then just use `Id` for relations and if for any reason you want to use the reference code for search purpose, reporting or UI purpose, you have it in your business logic.

Comment: Please confirm after the updated `UniqueRefNo` is it possible to change the value later on any action in your workflow?

Comment: @RezaAghaei My main intention is to rename the file as per unique reference number and save the name in the column as R0001.pdf here 1 is identity key value. The file name is chosen from file upload control in MVC. For this, I am writing a file to rename file third times after getting the identity key by database calls.

Comment: @UmairAnwaar The unique reference number can not be edited again.

Comment: There are different solutions for that. For example you can create a GUID column for `YourEntity`, Insert `YourEntity` with a GUID which you created in C# and then create the file with that GUID.

Comment: Another option, create an Identity column for `YourEntity` and after inserting `YourEntity`, read its `Id` (the property of the model will be updated automatically after insert) and then create the file with that id.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Can I get that identity key-value or that id value before calling the SaveChanges() method.

Comment: No, for identity you can get it after the `SaveChanges` without any additional call. But for the GUID, you create it before `SaveChanges`. It's one of the scenarios that GUID is pretty good option.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I understood what you want to ask but in that case, the filename in the folder will be saved as 9245fe4a-d402-451c-b9ed-9c1a04247482.pdf but I want like RC0001.pdf because it will be justifiable and self-explanatory when downloaded the file by the user. As per your suggestion, it will solve the repeated call. Thanks.

Comment: Those ids and references are for programmer, not for the user. If you are concerned about a good download name, you can set the name of download file in the download action later. But even using identity, if you save the file after your entity, then you can save the file with `RC00001`, because you now `yourEntity.Id` without any extra query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207110/discussion-between-suraj-kumar-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: If you are using SQL server you can use a SEQUENCE

Comment: No need for triggers or hacks... No need for stored procedures. No need for computer columns..... You can use SEQUENCES!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an option, you can create an identity column and a computed column, in the computed column, calculate the desired value based on identity column. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Code]  AS (('R'+ REPLICATE('0',(5) - LEN(CONVERT([NVARCHAR](50),[Id])))) +
        CONVERT([NVARCHAR](50),[Id]))
)
```

Then when you insert into table using EF or a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1]([Name]) VALUES (N'Something')
```

The result is:

```
| Id   | Name           | Code              |
.............................................
| 1    | Something      | R00001            |
```

**Important Note**

> Before choosing any solution, no matter computed column, sequence, or trigger,
> make sure you need to store such computed code in database. **I think you don't need to generate and store the reference code at database side**, it's enough to use the
> key of the entity as a reference number / foreign key wherever a
> logical or physical relation is needed.

***Using Identity column:*** You can define an identity `Id` column. Then after you insert `yourEnitty` in db, after `SaveChanges()`, `yourEntity.Id` will contain the new inserted identity value and you don't need an additional call to db. Then you can use the same id as reference (for example as file name).

***Using Guid column:*** You can define a Guid `Id` column. Then before you insert `yourEnitty` in db assign `Guid.NewId()` to the `Id` column and then you can use the same guid as reference (for example as file name).

Consider the following points:

- The name or key of the file in your storage and the key of the entity in your database is your territory and end user has nothing to do with it.
- You may want to use a storage like Azure Blob, SQL Database, File System and so on and in any of these storage technologies, you may use different key/name for the file.
- The only thing that end use can say is, "I'd like to see the link of files with a friendly name", or "I'd like to have a friendly name when downloading a file" and its really easy for you to provide such friendly name in grids or when download.

My advice is store and retrieve the file using a key, like a guid key. Then in your download action you can easily send the file with a different name for download, for example:

```
public ActionResult Download(Guid id)
{
    var file = Server.MapPath($"~/Content/uploads/{id}.pdf";
    return File(file, "application/pdf", "something.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Although to get the database table's identity key value I need second call must after SaveChanges() in EF. Apart from that this is an exact alternative of my requirement.

Comment: Assuming you have a `myEntity` variable and doing so to save it: `db.MyEntities.Add(myEntity); db.SaveChanges();` then without any additional request to db, `myEntity.Id` will contain the inserted identity for your entity.

Comment: Anyway, you know your requirements better :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem of the second call to the database seems to be solved by database triggers after insert.

All other code options will not solve the problem of the second call like using stored procedures or execute SQL queries.

My suggestion is to split the work into the database level done by triggers and C# code to solve your file saving issue.

After insert trigger: https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/41414/sql-server-coding-the-after-insert-trigger-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server then this is the perfect job for SEQUENCES.

SEQUENCES have been around for while now in the Microsoft world.

They are designed to produce sequential values that can be global to an entire database.

Very easy to create and very easy to consume.

Please take a look at the documentation:
[SEQUENCES IN SQL SERVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You can then use the output of the sequence to "compose" a string or even just use the value to set a primary key or unique key column in the insert statement.

SEQUENCES are the perfect alternative to "Identity" columns.

And they are compliant with the ANSI/ISO standard for SQL.

Here is link with some information and even examples on how to use SEQUENCES:

[EXAMPLES AND OTHER INFO](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-sequence-basics/)

SEQUENCES can also be used as default value constraints in columns during insert statements.

**WARNING:** As far as I know this feature was made available in SQL Server 2012 and higher....

Comment: Sequence doesn't give anything more than Identity in this case.  While I've already mentioned sequences in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48493725#48493725), but I'd say, the path to go is what I've shared in *Note* part of my answer.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I do not agree. Identity is autogenerated auto set value....While a sequence can be called from code to "compose" a new value for example a string using the squence output as a suffix like "R"+seqence output.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Also GUID columns make really bad case for PK, Unique Key or any other kind of index for performance reasons.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro My focus is not to achieve the uniqueness rather than it is how to get the identity key value before the calling SaveChanges() or at the same time when the SaveChanges() method is called.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Lastly Identity is only global to the table..... And really hard to recycle.

Comment: @SurajKumar exactly.... If instead of an Identity column you just use a integer or bigint... You can call the sequence before the insert and use the value for it.  This way you know the value of the "Id" column before calling SaveChanges....

Comment: @SurajKumar  SEQUENCES are safe and guaranteed to be sequential... So two calls will never return the same value. So you can call the sequence and use that value to set your "unique column" and to "compose" any other value that might depend on it BEFORE inserting the row.

Comment: I'm not going to argue about because these decisions are highly dependent to a lot of non-functional requirement, and I clearly told *in this case*. The Guid is an example (which suites here very well), however OP can use identity as well.  Anyway, just give sequence a try (Is it worth the effort? Does it perform better considering the additional call over the wire to get the sequence from db?) and the you will see what you are gaining by using sequence.

Comment: @RezaAghaei have you ever used a SEQUENCE? What effort are you talking about? Creating a SEQUENCE takes 2 minutes.  And calling it is just a raw sql call to get a scalar...... It might even be faster than identity.  Also you do NOT need to make an "extra call over the wire" because a SEQUENCE can be set as DEFAULT value for a column or called from any other computational logic in SQL.

Comment: @RezaAghaei about GUID's it is a well known fact that they have performance issues when used as key columns for primary keys, unique keys or clustered indexes.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro *Set as default* → Then it will not be different from identity in this scenario. *A raw sql call to get a scaller* → Then it will be an extra call to get the sequence. *Have you ever used a SEQUENCE?* ← Prefer to not spend time on such a discussion. Good luck :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei setting as default would not be different than Identity except that you have a CHOICE.... With Identity you dont... And you keep saying you do not want to discuss this.... and yet here you are

Comment: @RezaAghaei by the way Microsoft is recommending to use SEQUENCE rather than Identity.... Because SEQUENCE is part of the SQL ANSI/ISO standard and it is used by Oracle and MySql as well.... While Identity it is not.